# Fermat's last theorem and Ramanujan's formulas

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Ramanujan's identities gave instances of the solutions to equations

$$x^3+y^3=z^3\pm 1$$

hence these are solutions failing FLT by plus or minus 1. Are there powers $n$ other than $3$ for which such close enough identities to FLT known?

Comment: Could you please show some solutions for $n=3$ ?

Comment: @OlivierRoche The "taxicab number" $1729 = 9^3 + 10^3 = 12^3 + 1$

Comment: Well I wrote a script, there are no solutions  $(x,y,z)\in \{2;\dots;100\}^3$ for $3<n\leqslant 100$.

Comment: $8^3+6^3=9^3-1$

Comment: The identity 9^3+10^3=12^3+1 is one instance of approximate Fermat's equation satisfied for n=3. This was pointed out by Ramamnujan to Hardy. Hardy asked him that time if knew other such instance. Ramanujan had replied that he did not know but felt that another such instance of numbers must be very large.